# How to call number keyboard automatically?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, keyboard, numbers

I'm beginner in Java Android developing. I'm using Eclipse SDK 3.6.1 version. I'm trying to do this thing: when I start my application it calling to input a pin code, but if you want to input a number you have to click on the pin field. How to call number keyboard automatically? I'm using Samsung gt-i5500, it's touchscreen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've not actually tried this, but you could try setting `android:inputType="phone"` on the pin field, then calling `requestFocus` on that field in your code.

Answer (score 2):

You just have to set `android:inputType="number"` for your pin editText as below:

```
  <EditText   
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
android:inputType="number" 
></EditText>
```

And a numeric keyboard will be shown when user clik on the field.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can tell the UI (specifically the TextView:EditText) what type of field you are dealing with by setting the inputType. Here are a [list of the available input types](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android%3ainputType), and, depending on what you choose, you'll receive that keyboard when you enter data into the field.

In your case, you're most likely going to want inputType:number. See the link I provided for the entire list of available options.